# Is it possible to implement Tesseract in Phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, ocr, tesseract

I developed an Android app that uses the free OCR Tesseract and Android NDK.

Now I want to use Tesseract but in a Phonegap App.

I already searched and found OCRApiService but is not free. I want to use something free like Tesseract.

Is it possible to implement Tesseract in Phonegap? How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you've already gotten Tesseract to work in an Android project you are most of the way there. You'll just have to write a plugin to wrap the Tesseract functionality so it can be called from JavaScript.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/) you have tesseract for android, I think it shouldn't be difficult to create the plugin from that code